# How to go through a ManyToMany field in chunks in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display sets of three objects in a HTML template in a tiled interface. So, for example, an Album model has a ManyToMany field with specific photos. I want to iterate through the photos and show them in sets of three in the view. Currently, I can get all the photos using `{{ for photo in album.images.all }}` in the template, but don't know how to get the results in sets of three.

How would I go about chunking the results into sets of three so that I can then iterate through the sets of three for the template? Or is there a way to get the total length and then index of specific elements using the Template tags?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display all the photos (separated in threes) in your view, or just three per page? If the latter, the Django paginator is the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django templates: Group items in Threes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845227/django-templates-group-items-in-threes)

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for photo in album.images.all %}
    {{ photo }}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
        <hr> {# or some other markup #}
    {% endif
{% endfor %}
```

You might also do the grouping in your view. This might result in cleaner markup. See: [Django template {%for%} tag add li every 4th element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964972/django-template-for-tag-add-li-every-4th-element#answer-11965885)