# Displaying object in chunks across html table in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have list of over 100 categories I want to display across html table where(category data is from django model)

```
class Category():
 name = models.Charfield(max=200)
```

like

```
<table>
<tr><td>cat 1</td><td>cat 2</td><td>cat 3</td><td>cat 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>cat 5</td><td>cat 6</td><td>cat 7</td><td>cat 8</td></tr>
<tr>......</tr>
</table>
```

here cat = category name

please note each table row is holding 4 table data(where each td is in turns hold a category name)

I know i could output them singly but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process your list and then display it accordingly in the template. See [Django template {%for%} tag add li every 4th element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964972/django-template-for-tag-add-li-every-4th-element/11965885#11965885).