# Render django formset with two forms per row

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to render a particular field in each form where each pair of fields should  appear in a single row.

```
<form method="post" action="settings/developer" id="ipwhitelist-form">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="whitelistips">
      <input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="{{apikey}}">
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          {{ formset.0.id }}
          {% bootstrap_field formset.0.ip_range placeholder="0.0.0.0/0" addon_after='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          {{ formset.1.id }}
          {% bootstrap_field formset.1.ip_range placeholder="0.0.0.0/0" addon_after='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          {{ formset.2.id }}
          {% bootstrap_field formset.2.ip_range placeholder="0.0.0.0/0" addon_after='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          {{ formset.3.id }}
          {% bootstrap_field formset.3.ip_range placeholder="0.0.0.0/0" addon_after='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- 10 more fieldsto come -->
  </form>
```

In the above, I just hard-coded the form number and accessed it through `formset.form-num` . What I want is to do iterate over forms  and then access two forms at a time .. Note that I want only one field from each form to get rendered...

Comment: This question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964972/django-template-for-tag-add-li-every-4th-element

Comment: @Alasdair great now it works fine..